# Why does JQuery $.post send the first variable with a leading ampersand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This small snippet of code I'm using is causing issues because the request string is coming through to apache as "delete.php&id={id}&confirm=yes" instead of "delete.php?id={id}&confirm=yes".

```
if(result) {
    var posting = $.post( '/support_ticket/delete.php', {id: tickId, confirm: 'yes'});
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        var content = $( data ).find( '#main' );
            bootbox.alert(content);
        });
    }
```

As far as I can recall I've never had this issue before and don't understand why it's doing this.

Comment: It doesn't for me; can you provide any more details?

Comment: Where are you seeing that url? In the browser tools, fiddler, or on the server?

Comment: @Jason That's the URL I'm seeing when I echo out the REQUEST_URI on the page it's hitting.

Comment: @DCoder What do you suggest I log from $.post? I'm using jquery 1.10.3

Comment: Better idea - look at Developer Tools first, to make sure that jQuery *is* at fault, before digging into it. If the request created by the browser is valid, then jQuery is not to blame.

Comment: @DCoder it does seem that the request jquery is sending is fine. I guess my issue is elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: The issue turned out to be a misconfigured htaccess file.

Comment: @Morgan It might be helpful to people in the future if you posted your solution as an answer and accepted it.